# Flow Typed - Higher order components - prop injecting

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I attempting props injection with higher order component, but I can't get it right.

Why is this incorrect please?

```
/* @flow */

import * as React from 'react';

type FooType = {
  foo: string, 
  bar: string
};

const Foo = ({ foo, bar }: FooType)=> <div>{foo}{bar}</div>;

const addBlah = <T: {}>(Component: React.ComponentType<T & { bar: string }>) => 
        ({...props}) => <Component {...props} bar={"bar"}/>;

const WithBlah = addBlah(Foo);

const result = ()=> <WithBlah foo="foo" />;
```

[TryFlow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBdkwBDAZzACUBTUgY2KnzizAHJ87H2BudQgE8cNMADE4cACrDRAXjABvVGDBRJALjDlC+DADsA5gBowKsACNS+LTr1HUAX36p6cfTvGSwCgBSK1SVMrfDBHLQlpWQBKOQA+MAAeABMMADc4xXU4R0UQx0TgVIyXNw9iUmTkgCEYUgALHySpLUVHON8AYVY8fRp9Qi1aBkIAOm7cd37CGRFEqTAAMiVLa1tdA0MwuOifBPNVQ7B-UdOcFhxyR134pIne6aVT0fO4S8dV-DlFACIQn8cwDipXcngA6hhCPVag0mpUanV6r5ItF+Ecjq5QcQuOQAK4wYh+WIJRIQqEwxrZOQ-bI-MBA3hAA)

Answer (score 1):

Right, going with documentation seems like the return type should contain a `$Diff` with an optional type of void.

here is how it looks like

```
/* @flow */

import * as React from 'react';

type FooType = {
  foo: string, 
  bar: string
};

const Foo = ({ foo, bar }: FooType)=> <div>{foo}{bar}</div>;

const addBlah = <T: {}>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>): React.ComponentType<$Diff<T, { bar: string | void }>> => 
        ({...props}) => <Component {...props} bar={"bar"}/>;

const WithBlah = addBlah(Foo);

const result = ()=> <WithBlah foo="foo" />;
```